# Android Studio: Automatic search in Project view upon class creation

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

As the title suggests.

After creating a new Kotlin class in Android Studio, as soon as I start typing, the Project view Search starts. It's really annoying. Any idea why this might happen or how it could be resolved?

It's not something that happens *sometimes*, it's always happening.

Comment: Do you mean the focus is switched from the editor back to the Project view? Do you see the same behavior if you close the Project view panel? Does it it go away if you disable all of the non-bundled plugins and restart the IDE? File | Settings | Plugins | ⚙ | Disable all downloaded plugins

Comment: Thanks for the tip about disabling all downloaded plugins! This issue comes from 'Quick File Preview' by Martin Sommer. I'll try and get in touch with him!